# Syntax error on dynamic element of a button with selenium

Tags: selenium, dynamic, find, element

I was trying to find out a dynamic element of a button from a html page with selenium

The syntax is given below

```
toggle=driver.find_element_by_xpath'//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div/nav/div/div[2]')
```

but I'm getting a syntax error as an output.

I'm using python and google chrome driver in this purpose. Also is there a better way to find dynamic elements, specially button elements?

Comment: Please include your code and the full traceback error.

Comment: If that is indeed the error...  I'm noticing you're missing an opening ```(``` after the ```_xpath```.  i.e.   ```toggle=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//....')```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Super User/PycharmProjects/webautomation/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("abcd") 

toggle=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div/nav/div/div[2]')
toggle.click()
```

```
 AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

---

Yup this is the problem now the complete code is given, and I want to click the button by the "xpath" or any other way.

Thanks for your quick response